# Partition of set induced by relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$n, n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4 ∈ Z^+$

and f : A → B

where |A| = $n$ and B = {a, b, c, d} is function where $|f^{−1}(a)|$ = $n_1, $ $|f^{−1}(b)|$ = $n_2, $ $|f^{−1}(c)|$ =$ n_3, $$|f^{−1}(d)|$ = $n_4 $
and 
$n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = n.$

On set A we define relation R: xRy, if x, y ∈ A and f(x) = f(y).

a) find |R|

b) Is R equivalance? If so, what is the partition of A induced by R?

I have no idea how to solve a), for b) I know that R is equivalence when it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, but I have no idea how to prove it and no idea how to determine what is the partition of A induced by R. Any ideas how to solve this, please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Define $N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4$ to be the sets of elements $f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}(b),f^{-1}(c),f^{-1}(d)$, respectively.

Then $xRy$ if and only if $x,y$ are in the same $N_i$.

Reflexive:- Any $x\in A$ is in the same $N_i$ as itself.

Symmetric:- If $x$ and $y$ are in the same $N_i$ then so, obviously, are $y$ and $x$.

Transitive:- If $x$ and $y$ are in the same $N_i$ and if $y$ and $z$ are in the same $N_i$ then so are $x$ and $z$.

$A$ is partitioned into $N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4$.